# rel attribute on <form> tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, rel

Well, I have this form tag which works perfectly.

```
<form action="searchresult.php" method="post">
        <?php
        require('connect.inc');
        $sql1="SELECT room_type,room_id FROM room";
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

        echo "<select name=roomtype value=''></option>";
        while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo "<option value=$nt[room_type]>$nt[room_type]</option>";
            }
        echo "</select>";
        mysql_close();
        ?> 

    </td>
    <td>    
        <input type='hidden' name='clientid' value="<?php echo $clientid; ?>">
        <input type="text" class="w8em format-y-m-d highlight-days-67 range-low-today" name="chkin" id="sd" value="" maxlength="20" readonly />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="w8em format-y-m-d highlight-days-67 range-low-today" name="chkout" id="ed" value="" maxlength="20" readonly />
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' id="button1" value="Check Room Availabilty">

</form>
```

This opens up to a new page named "searchresult.php"

But,what I need to know is, how to display this .php file in a pop up style.

I am currently using facebox as my pop up,and I use it like this:

```
<a rel="facebox" href="searchresult.php">Check Room Availability</a>
```

But to no success, the inputs are not passing to the next page,so I get errors.

I know variables can be pass through the a tag like this

```
echo'<a rel="facebox" href=editroom.php?id=' . $row3["room_id"] . '>' . 'Edit' . '</a>';
```

But my case now is , I need the inputs to be pass.

I declare this codes in every page.

```
<link href="src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
    closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'
  })
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us all the code relevant to your facebox install? Do you have all the relevant CSS and JS in place?

Comment: yup, I can use the facebox correctly throughout my page.. wait ill put the code in the post

Comment: Are you getting JavaScript errors? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could attach a method to the form submit to call

```
 jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'searchresult.php' });
```

You will ofcourse have to pass some URL parameters in order for it to display the relevant results

Something like this will work:

```
 $('#search').submit(function() {
      $.facebox({ ajax: 'searchresult.php?search=&search2=' });
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: im using this jquery,ill try to add that.

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'
      })
    })
  </script>

Comment: You'll need to create variables from the input values as well don't forget